# What is that frog toy that Misaka loves?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

Misaka really loves this frog. Where does this frog come from? Does it exist both in anime and in real life (I feel like I've seen this frog somewhere before)?

[image: Misaka and Gekota]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very possible that you have seen it several times in the anime ( even in the game), it is a [gekota](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Gekota)

> Gekota (ゲコ太 Gekota?) is a popular mascot found in merchandise marketed to children in the Toaru Majutsu no Index universe. A Gekota fan is called a Gekoer. Misaka Mikoto is a huge fan of the franchise it belongs to, and much to her consternation gets her labeled as someone who is childish. 
>   [image]

And without a doubt there is also real life merchandise, and allot of look alike products, with a few samples bellow.

[image][image][image]

Comment: So, did Toaru Majutsu no Index get a gekota from another anime or Gekota become famous because of Toaru Majutsu no Index?

Comment: as stated in the first 2 lines of the quote. " in the Toaru Majutsu no Index universe". Made by Toaru Majutsu no Index. Popular due to Toaru Majutsu no Index.

Comment: Ah, I thought that I saw this Gekota much longer before Toaru Majutsu no Index. Maybe I was wrong...

Comment: @ShinobuOshino There are tons of look alike products. the sticky hand (the toy) had a few resembling Gekota face's, and I believe those where made before Toaru Majutsu no Index even was released.

Comment: The real life counterpart you might be thinking about might be Kerokerokeroppi which is something similar to the Gekota.